# Python, KeyError: "There is no item named '{filename}' in the archive

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a code to try to extract the length of each file in a directory.
I cannot figure out why I am getting error : `KeyError: "There is no item named 'Test1' in the archive"`

Code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

import pandas as pd


def process_files(files: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    file_mapping = {}
    for file in files:
        data_mapping = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)), sheet_name=None)

        row_counts = []
        for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
            row_counts.append(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))

        file_mapping.update({file: sum(row_counts)})

    frame = pd.DataFrame([file_mapping]).transpose().reset_index()
    frame.columns = ["file_name", "row_counts"]

    return frame




path = r'//Stack/Over/Flow/testfiles/'
zip_files = (str(x) for x in Path(path).glob("*.zip"))
df = process_files(zip_files)
print(df)
```

my files:

[image]

inside test1 zip:

[image]

any help would be appreicated.

Edit - How would I apply the code to the zip files in subdirectories like so? So within 2022 - 05 there would be zip files, and within 2022-06 there would be zip files, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each file in your archive, you call this line:

```py
ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)
```

This means that within each zipfile given by `file`, you must have a file within the archive with the same name, but without the extension (i.e., the [stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)).

So for this to work, you'd need to have a structure like this:

```
test1.zip
    test1
test2.zip
    test2
```

Instead, you have the file `TestInside1.xls` - very different from the filename `test1`. You have a number of options for constructing valid paths for file names inside the zip archive - for one, you could use [`ZipFile.namelist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist).

For example, you could replace this:

```py
data_mapping = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)), sheet_name=None)
```

with this:

```py
archive = ZipFile(file)

# find file names in the archive which end in `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.xlsb`, ...
files_in_archive = archive.namelist()
excel_files_in_archive = [
    f for f in files_in_archive if Path(f).suffix[:4] == ".xls"
]
# ensure we only have one file (otherwise, loop or choose one somehow)
assert len(excel_files_in_archive) == 1

# read in data
data_mapping = pd.read_excel(
    BytesIO(archive.read(excel_files_in_archive[0])),
    sheet_name=None,
)
```

Comment: Thanks! this works nicely. However How do I perform this on subfolders? See my edit.

Comment: you can definitely feel free to look at the [zipfile docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and other stack overflow questions which definitely answer this question. you can also use the full internal path to specify whatever you'd like to read from within the zipfile. but I'll let you do that (easy) research - I answered the question as you wrote it. extending the answer to multiple subfolders is just a matter of putting this in a loop.